# How to calculate sum inside awk command in unix?

Tags: unix, awk

My newProcessFile.txt looks like this

```
total 16
-rw-rw-r--    1 jaind    staff             0 Jul 14 08:54 cdim_landing_addl_addr.out
-rw-rw-r--    1 jaind    staff             0 Jul 17 06:13 cdim_merge_alert_log.out
-rw-rw-r--    1 jaind    staff             0 Jul 11 09:02 merge_log.out
-rw-rw-r--    1 jaind    staff             0 Nov 06 07:12 newProcessFile.txt
-rw-------    1 jaind    staff           969 Aug 13 02:22 nohup.out
-rw-r-----    1 jaind    staff           474 Apr 28 2014  profile_old
drwxr-x---    2 jaind    staff           256 Nov 06 04:45 test_Chiranjib
```

Whenever I am trying to compute the sum at column numbered 7 it prints the outputs as 0.

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS = ","; sum = 0; count = 0 } {if(NR >= 2){sum = sum + $7; count ++; print $1,$2,$5,sum}}' newProcessFile.txt
```

Sum is not being computed . What am I missing ?

Comment: column 7? You're adding the days of the month??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the field separator from your awk command as you are not using "," to separate fields.

```
awk 'NR >= 2{sum += $7; print $1,$2,$5,sum}' newProcessFile.txt
```

I have removed the counter variable as well as it was not used anywhere.

Comment: I have made some changes to your code, feel free to roll back the edit if you like. Hopefully the edit summary is self-explanatory :)

Comment: It's not strictly necessary to initialize variables to zero.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're doing a directory listing of the current directory, you really shouldn't parse the output of ls. Here are 2 alternatives:

```
stat -c "%s" * | awk '{sum+=$1} END {print sum}'
```

```
perl -E '-f $_ and $sum += -s _ for glob("*"); say $sum'
```